# NodeJS/Mongoose: Cannot Push ObjectID into Document Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a `post` document and then saving it. After saving it, I would like to obtain the ID of the saved post. I would then like to insert this ID into the `array "posts"` in the `"user"`document.

However, the problem is that after saving the post and getting the callback `"savedPost"`, I am not able to push its ID into the `"posts"` array in the `"user"` document. It returned `"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"`.

When I checked MongoDB, I can see that `"post"` is indeed saved into the database, so the problem seems to be after the callback. I tried searching online but none of the answers helped me.

Here are the codes.

**NodeJS/Mongoose:**

```
post.save(function(err, savedPost){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //problem seems to start here
        var postId = {id: 'savedPost._id'};
        user.post.push(postId);
        user.save();
    }
});
```

**User Schema**

```
var UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    posts: [
        {id: String}
    ],
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: @HassanImam It seems a bit confusing. Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: do you mean `user.posts` and not `user.post`? Notice the `s` at the end

Comment: flagging to close because typo

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Didn't notice the typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your answer
It should be `user.posts` not `user.post`

But aside that remember the post can be empty for a user without post.
So you should initialize the array if it's empty and does not exist.

```
user.posts=user.posts || [ ]
```